# node-quickbooks reconnect method no longer gives expected response

Tags: node.js, sdk, quickbooks

I am trying to get new access tokens before they expire using reconnect api endpoint, but the api call to https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Reconnect is being redirected to https://quickbooks.intuit.com/learn-support/en-us/do-more-with-quickbooks/third-party-app-security-requirements-updating-soon/01/428295, rather the expected response. Am i missing something here? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Intuit's documentation, you're using the wrong URL:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#refresh-the-token

Did you try using the correct URL?

From the docs:

```
To refresh an access token, your application sends an HTTPS POST request to 
Intuit’s authorization server 
(https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer) 
that includes the following parameters:
```

Comment: I am using node-quickbooks sdk, which has reconnect method, which internally calls api https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Reconnect.

Comment: Sounds like you need to either update, or fix the SDK. That's the wrong URL.